# Simple Java Pyramid using nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I am having a great deal of trouble trying to figure out a way to create a pyramid using a user's input. Here is what it is suppose to look like.

```
Enter a number between 1 and 9: 4
O
O
O
O
OOOO
OOOO 
OOOO 
OOOO
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
```

This is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 9: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        for (int rows = number; number < i; rows++){
            System.out.print("O");
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }
}
```

I completely understand of what I am trying to accomplish, but I do not completely understand how for loops work. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lost!

Comment: `for` loops execute the code inside their bodies as long as the condition in their declaration is true.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Which is exactly how `while` and `do while` loops work as well...

Comment: @nhgrif Quoting.. `but I do not completely understand how for loops work` Maybe he doesn't know while/do while yet. In this case a for loop should be better since he needs to `iterate`.

Comment: I suggest you to do the problem first in your head. If you cannot solve this problem in your head then you will hardly solve it with code. Do step by step the program using paper and then try to replicate that in code.

Comment: @porfiriopartida `For loops` have initialization and update statements though... and that might be part of the confusion for the original poster.

Comment: Have you read the appropriate page in Oracle's Java tutorial?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a `for` loop works like this

```
// Take this example (and also try it)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   System.out.println(i);
}


// Explanation
for(int i = 0; // the value to start at  - in this example 0
    i < 10;    // the looping conditions - in this example if i is less than 10 continue 
               //         looping executing the code inclosed in the { }
               //         Once this condition is false, the loop will exit
    i++)       // the increment of each loop - in this exampleafter each execution of the
               //         code in the { } i is increments by one
{
   System.out.println(i);  // The code to execute
}
```

Experiment using different starting value, conditions and increments, Try these:

```
for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){System.out.println(i);}
for (int i = 5; i >  0; i--){System.out.println(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the for-loops with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number ; i++){
        System.out.println("O");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < number ; j++){
            System.out.print("O");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= number ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i ; j++){
            System.out.print("O");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**OUTPUT (for number = 6):**

```
O
O
O
O
O
O
OOOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOO
OOOOOO
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
OOOOO
OOOOOO
```

Comment: An explanation might have been more help than actual code.  I'm sure that the OP would rather learn something MORE from their homework than how to copy-paste code.  I am seriously considering a downvote, even though your solution is correct.

Comment: @DavidWallace when I'm not sure how to do something - I look at code examples, and if the logic is a bit complicated to grasp (for example, bucket/radix sort) I might even run with a debugger. That said, if you feel that this answer is not useful feel free to downvote - I promise to not take it personally ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it a lot better now! An explanation as David Wallace suggested is far inferior compared to actual code. The best way to learn is to look at it, understand it, then reapply it on your own. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Some for insight..

```
for(INIT_A_VARIABLE*; CONDITION_TO_ITERATE; AN_OPERATION_AT_THE_END_OF_THE_ITERATION)
```

- You can init more than one variable or call any methods. In java you can init or call the same type of variable/method.

These are valid code statements:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) // inits i as 0, increases i by 1 and stops if i<=5 is false.
 for (int i = 0, j=1, k=2; i <= 5; i++) //inits i as 0, j as 1 and k as 2.
 for (main(args),main(args); i <= 5; i++) //Calls main(args) twice before starting the for statement. IT IS NONSENSE, but you can do that kind of calls there.
 for (int i = 0; getRandomBoolean(); i++) //You can add methods to determine de condition or the after iteration statement.
```

Now.. about your homework.. I'd use something like this:

Iterate through the limit of rows and add spaces and the desired character to its position. The position will be determined by the row you are in.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (int j = 5; j > i; j--) {
    System.out.print(' ');
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print("O ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```