# How could a for loop be applicated in this?

Tags: java

I had this task on a test to create a program in Java that simply writes an pyramid of X letters, based on the natural number a typed in.
Meaning n=4 would be printing out

```
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
```

Ive been thinking over this for hours and I think something really obvious,which I cant see, is the problem.

Any help is really appreciated.

PS: Im just a beginner

Comment: Beginner or not, you should at least attempt before coming here. `"I've been thinking over this for hours..."`  doesn't tell us much of use. I'm sure you can give us something that you've tried, especially if you've been mulling this for "hours".

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: It cant be more than 14 lines of code. Show us 7

Comment: In those hours, did you never consider typing "java for pyramid" into google?

Comment: Dang i found a 15 line one on s.o. they need to optimize it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373738/simple-java-program-of-pyramid

Comment: It does include like 2 extra spaces might be too difficult to edit and re-use

Comment: @TotZam let's not assume those skills

Comment: Still has javac to deal with

Comment: Let's hope for better questions in the future. I'm sure that this will be the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Java Pyramid using nested for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106399/simple-java-pyramid-using-nested-for-loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a begginer, its good that you didnt copied ready solution from the internet : )
You just need to think more about it.

Solution is very simple, your program need to know

- number of the line 'you' are currently at
- how many `X` to print on that line

Your loop should print letters from 1 to n amount

```
for lineNo belonging to N [1-n]
   print `x` lineNo times
```

Comment: Perfect answer +1. Edit: was perfect until you added code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to think generic:
I have to put N lines in the console. Ok
Then i have to have i x-es which is equivalent to the line number.
That resolves to 2 simple loops - hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

A Simple for loop that can do is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

}
```

A way to print can be concatenating an "X" after each iteration to a temporary String defined in your method.

Answer (score -2):

This simple method do exactly what you want :

```
  public static void pyramid(int x, char a){
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print(a);
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

Test :

```
Test.pyramid(4,'a');
```

Output :

```
a aa aaa aaaa
```

Comment: By giving a spoon-fed answer, you are doing the original poster a disservice by robbing him of the opportunity of discovering the code for himself.

Comment: Don't just give code-solution to homework questions. OP will not learn much from it. Instead take your time and write explanation which will allow OP create his own code.